# Can I optionally retrieve fields which are objects in either protobuf-net or NHibernate?

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate, client-server, protobuf-net

I have a Client Server app in the following way.

[image]

In the domain some classes have collections of children. Some children reference their parent.

The problem with the is when a request is made to the server for a child object, all other children are returned with the response.  In many circumstances it's very helpful to have access to the parent object from the child and I would prefer not to have to make a seperate request for the parent since that would result in more round trips.

Normally Nhibernates Lazy-Loading would take care of this but the interaction with protobuf-net (or any other serialization) means all the fields are accessed to be serialised. The client has no direct access to the database.

Is it possible to limit the object reference depth in either protobuf-net or Nhibernate in such a way that I can include in the request to the server a flag saying don't load more than 2 objects deep.

e.g.
Order - Order Item - Delivery Information.

A limit of one on a request for an order would mean don't load the delivery information. A limit of 0 would mean don't load the order items.

Altenatively is it possible to optionally stop references being loaded (the limit is either 0 or unlimited) this is more restrictive but possibly more viable to implement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

protobuf-net supports the ShouldSerialize* pattern (in common with several BCL implementations, including the IDE/PropertyGrid, and XmlSerializer).

If you have:

```
[ProtoMember(1)]
public int Whatever { get; set; }
```

And a corresponding:

```
public bool ShouldSerializeWhatever() {
    ...
}
```

Then Whatever is only serialized if ShouldSerializeWhatever returns true. This pattern is entirely name-based. The method can be public or non-public (but XmlSerializer only accepts public methods for this, so keep it public if you are using multiple serializers).

Comment: Thanks Marc, I'm defining my contract in IMO a wierd way that boils down to directly calling AddType, AddField and AddSubType.  I found a method `SetSpecified` on the return value of AddField which when given a method does the same?

Comment: @James - yes, that's the same thing; naming is due to the `*Specified` BCL pattern that is also supported, and the fact that this pattern allows 2-way usage (rather than `ShouldSerialize*`, which is 1-way). Same thing, though.

Answer (score 0):

Well, first off, this doesn't really have anything to do with protobuf-net as it is just the serialier, and just serializes what you give to it, so you just have to give it 2 levels deep.

This would really all be done in your logic. What I'm assuming you are doing is serializing your actual objects that are coming out of nhibernate. What you likely want to do is [introduce DTO's](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataTransferObject.html) that will be used as the response from the service instead, and copy the data from your objects to the DTO's, thus allowing you to go only 2 levels deep.

Copying the datas to DTO's can be tedious and there are projects like [AutoMapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) that aim to make your life simpler in that aspect, but I'm not sure how much control over the mapping you have to where you could specify only go 2 levels deep, so manual mapping may be required.

Comment: I wondered if protobuf-net had an option to "Don't serialise this member". which would allow Nhibernate's lazy loading to become effective again. You're right in that I'm just serialising the domain objects directly.

Comment: I would argue for DTO route, because while you can add attributes to ignore members, likely you will run into somewhere else where you will want to serialize that member when sending to the client, so then you are back to square one since you are serializing the core object rather than mapping.

Comment: Here's an example of what i'm talking about: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/06/30/how-we-do-mvc-view-models/

Comment: @JamesB it does have **exactly** that option - I agree with you that this is, at least in part, a serializer concern